# how to integrate postmates API with shopify

Tags: api, shopify

i'm wondering if anyone has built and app or a framework to integrate [postmates](https://postmates.com/developer) with shopify.

```
POST /v1/customers/:customer_id/delivery_quotes
POST /v1/customers/:customer_id/deliveries
GET /v1/customers/:customer_id/deliveries/:delivery_id
```

Comment: Hi there, I am also looking for the kind of similar solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400076/postmates-integration-with-shopify-shipping-carrier-services

Also posted at Shopify forum as well : https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/postmates-integration-with-shopify-fulfillment-shipping-carrier-services-240300

Let's hope some one from Mars really can help us out.

Answer (score 1):

We have an official integration with Shopify: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/shipping/on-demand-deliveries/postmates

Comment: Did this come to anything?