# Postmates integration with Shopify Shipping/Carrier services

Tags: api, shopify

We are looking to integrate this application:

https://postmates.com/developer/docs into our Shopify platform.

For how it works please check: http://blog.postmates.com/post/104856343907/a-technical-perspective-on-the-postmates-api.

So we are looking for add a Carrier Service to our store.
And As Postmates provides services to few regions as follows we will add other mutiple shipping options for non-Postmates supported regions.

Postmates is currently available in the San Francisco Bay Area (San Francisco, East Bay, South Bay), New York City, Chicago, Los Angeles, Washington DC, Seattle, Austin, Boston, Philadelphia, Miami, San Diego, Denver, Las Vegas and Orange County.

I have contacted both Shopify and Postmates, who both say there is no app already built to directly integrate this into their account.  With that said, Postmates claims that it has been done before where a user creates a Private App and connect it through API key that way.
Could you please advice on below:

1. Review the documentation that I sent over in the above link
2. Research how to integrate this into a Shopify backend, any way possible?...whether through private app or not, but through API for sure.
3. potential solutions for postmate shopify API integration
4. potential solutions for app creation and/or any management of the process.

Also please note:  So basically we want to add Postmates shipping service for some regions only ( as it supports few regions only https://postmates.com/help Topic : "What cities is Postmates available in?" )
and for other regions we will have different shipping charges+ methods etc...

So at backend which things & how we need to setup the things.As per this : http://docs.shopify.com/api/carrierservice

Are there any limitations or restrictions?

Please advice if I am missing any information or any specific detail to mention here.

Is there any creative folks who like to dive deep into space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shopify API's carrier service resource (http://docs.shopify.com/api/carrierservice) is indeed the solution you're looking for.

Whenever a customer of your Shopify store is placing an order during checkout, after he has entered his billing & shipping address, Shopify can send a rate request to the carrier service you have registered. This post request contains all data about the items in cart and the customer.

Your carrier service app needs to accept this POST request, calculate the corresponding shipping rates - in your case by yet another API call to the Postmates API - and then return a JSON response in the format that Shopify defines in the docs. If all goes well, the shipping rate(s) your app has returned will then be shown in the checkout.

You can code your app such that for the cities that Postmates doesn't support, your carrier service will return no rates.

We've built such an integration with Shippo (https://apps.shopify.com/shippo), supporting many other carriers. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: This helped me display customer carrier rates. But, how does one then send the delivery information to Postmates (or any carrier) after the order is placed in Shopify? Is there a webhook or another API to use?

Comment: You can use Shopify Webhooks (https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhooks/using-webhooks) and register a webhook for Order creation. Alternatively you could poll the API Order endpoint frequently and check for order updates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with shopify (developer store). And recently I have the same error.

**Error description:**
I added a Carrier Service successfully. Add zone rates, and set in the callback function a default response to test it (I took this json from shopify doc):

```
 $rates = [
            "rates" => 
            [
                [
                    "service_name"      => "BlueExpress",
                    "service_code"      => "ON",
                    "total_price"       => "1295",
                    "description"       => "This is the fastest option by far",
                    "currency"          => "PES",
                    "min_delivery_date" => "2021-04-20 14:48:45 -0400",
                    "max_delivery_date" => "2021-05-12 14:48:45 -0400"
        
                ]
            ]
        ];

        return json_encode($rates);
```

But, when the customer is in the checkout...get the next message:
[image]

**To solve it you have to add this options in the create/update Carrier Service request:**
"service_discovery": false,
"register": true

In this way I solved it

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Comment: You are right. Sorry.
Anyway I want to tell you that I could solve it. When you create a Carrier Service, you have to add this option in the request:"service_discovery": false,
    "register": true

Comment: @EsTeAa I edit my answer adding the way I solve it!